# SvelteKit on macOS Monterey 12.0.1 (Safari 15.1) - Running on localhost without https but Safari tries to load resources via https

Tags: https, safari, vite, sveltekit, macos-monterey

Running a local dev server using SvelteKit on macOS Monterey 12.0.1. When opening the dev site in Safari 15.1, I'm getting errors for my images :

> Unsafe attempt to load URL
> https://localhost:3000/images/icons/icons.svg from origin
> http://localhost:3000. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
> [Error] Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. (https://localhost:3000/images/logos/logo.svg, line 0)
> [Error] Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. (https://localhost:3000/.svelte-kit/dev/runtime/internal/start.js, line 0)
> [Error] Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. (https://localhost:3000/images/home/home0.jpg, line 0)

1. I'm accessing the site via http://localhost:3000 - not https://localhost.
2. There's no **base** element and all images use a relative href (`/images/icons/icons.svg`).
3. I checked window.location.protocol in Safari's console and it confirmed "http:" (also, window.location.origin = "http://localhost:3000").
4. Problem does not happen with Chrome or FireFox (latest versions).

Googled for suggestions and found advice to delete cookies, local storage and databases in Safari for localhost (which I tried though localhosts did not disappear from the list and now says "Databases").
[image]

I also found a recommendation to quite Safari then run the following shell commands:

```
killall nsurlstoraged
rm -f ~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist
launchctl start /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.nsurlstoraged.plist
```

None of that appears to apply to Monterey.

Any thoughts about what I need to do other than `npm run dev --https --open` (which works but...)?

It may have been related to my Monterey upgrade. I didn't notice because I have been working in https mode lately.

For SvelteKit folks, I did `rm -rf .svelte-kit` before `npm run dev --open`

Comment: I've had a similar issue. I upgraded my OS to Monterey and my Safari is uptodate (v15.1). I had to change browser for now till this issue is fixed

Comment: Been using `npm run dev --open --https` but not happy with it.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I am still on Big Sur and Safari v15.0